# How to handle responsive design widths when portable devices have a higher pixel density?

Tags: responsive-design

OK I'm new to responsive design and so bear with me whilst I try to explain this. So it seems that the way responsive design works is that different css media queries are triggered based on the users window width. If thats the case then don't the new iphones and tablets mess this up because of the devices high pixels per inch density compared to desktops 72ppi? So the web pages that were once designed for say mobiles at 320px are not triggered by say the iphone5 because of the higher ppi (336) at 640x1136 and instead say trigger the web page intended for tablets when this is'nt ideal?

I aprechiate you guys helping me clear things up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CSS pixel and a screen pixel are not created equal. This blog post will hopefully help out.

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html